# Stop audio when other media is played with Flutter AudioPlayers

Tags: flutter

I am developing a Flutter application that plays music in the background.
The app is playing in the background, but I would like it to stop playing (and resume afterwards) when the user starts playing something on Spotify or a video on YouTube. Also when they receive a phone call.

I'm currently using AppLifecycleState as described in [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html) and in the code as such:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
    _musicPlayer.player.stop();
  }
}
```

But I'm uncertain if any of the other states (inactive or paused) is more suitable.

Am I on the right path, or am I looking in the entirely wrong direction?